# iBeacon entry/exit notifications sent even when the specific notification is turned off

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, clregion

I'm trying to activate either the `notifyOnExit` or `notifyOnEntry` property of an iBeacon using `startMonitoringForRegion:`. However, `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:` is still called for `CLRegionStateInside` although `notifyOnEntry` was turned off or for `CLRegionStateOutside` although `notifyOnExit` was turned off (I confirmed that the flags were indeed turned of by checking the values for the region argument to `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:`).

So I'm getting more notifications that I want to. Obviously I could just check the flag values myself before posting the notifications, but I would like to first check here to see if anyone else has some insight (could post more code if need be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the `notifyOnExit` and `notifyOnEntry` flags affect the `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:` callback.  I think they may just affect the `locationManager:DidEnterRegion:` and `locationManager:DidExitRegion:` callbacks.

Have you tried using those?

Comment: Thanks, that's probably it. I will try those other callbacks out tomorrow and post the results here.

Comment: This was indeed the solution, thanks. I was just using the method `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:` because Apple did in their AirLocate sample project.